# How can I get the width of a link be only the width of the text's width?

Tags: html, css, hover

I managed to get pretty far into coding a function where the link's info will fade-in upon hovering over the link's title, but whenever I hover my mouse over the remaining space of the title's text, it triggers the link's info to fade-in. Is there a way I can get the activation-width only the with of the link's title? I am also looking for a CSS-only solution. If you can think of a more efficient method of achieving this, please let me know :)

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/kenhimself/vw87gj00/).

And here's a visualization of the problem since I'm not too familiar with code / developing terminology:
[image]

Many thanks in advance!

**HTML:**

```
<div class="page">
    <div class="text">
        <span class="title">Title &#40;More&#41;</span>
        <span class="info">
            Title Description over here
        </span>
    </div>
    <div class="image">
        <img src="..." alt="" />
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
body {
    font-family: helvetica;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 26px;
}
div.page {
    width:80%;
    max-width:960px;
    margin:0 auto;
    height:100%;
}
div.text {
    width:80%;
    max-width:960px;
    margin:0 auto;
}
div.text span.title {
    -webkit-transition: all .5s; 
    transition: all .5s;
}
div.text:hover span.title {
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
}
div.text span.info {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;  
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-transition: all .5s; 
    transition: all .5s;
}
div.text:hover span.info {
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
}
.image img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    padding-top: 10px;
}
.text{
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 9999;
}
.image{
    position:relative;
    top:20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its because your hover event is on a `div` which is a block level (width:100%) element.

You need to set it to display inline, or width auto so it doesnt take up the full width, then revert on hover:

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  font-family: helvetica;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 26px;
}
div.page {
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 100%;
}
div.text {
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
div.text:hover {
  display: block;
  width: 80%;
}
div.text span.title {
  -webkit-transition: all .5s;
  transition: all .5s;
}
div.text:hover span.title {
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}
div.text span.info {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: all .5s;
  transition: all .5s;
}
div.text:hover span.info {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}
.image img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  padding-top: 10px;
}
.text {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9999;
}
.image {
  position: relative;
  top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="page">
  <div class="text">
    <span class="title">Title &#40;More&#41;</span>
    <span class="info">
            Title Description over here<br/>
            More text<br/>
            More text<br/>
            And you know, text.<br/>
        </span>
  </div>
  <div class="image">
    <img src="http://www.graphicthoughtfacility.com/media/uploads/images/FW-SmallTray-WEB.jpg" alt="" />
    <img src="http://www.graphicthoughtfacility.com/media/uploads/images/FW-LargeBox-WEB.jpg" alt="" />
    <img src="http://www.graphicthoughtfacility.com/media/uploads/images/Formwork1_RGB-WEB.jpg" alt="" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You had a glitchy effect ... hover and move down the cursor you will see

Comment: @Danko - easily recitfied, but hard to know the best approach given the info provided by the OP.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, @SW4 -- but I'm afraid Danko is right, you're changes have affected the description directly.

Comment: @SW4 ah, is there a better approach than the one I suggested? I've been having difficulty executing this idea so I'm really open to better methods of achieving this. The functionality is very simple (in theory, that is). When the person hovers over the title, the text gets swapped by the description -- and when the person hovers out of the description, it fades back to the title.

Answer (score 0):

`div.text` is having 80% width and hence you can hover on the right side of it. Give the `div.text` a smaller width and give the `span.info` bigger width.

```
div.text {
    width:15%;
    max-width:960px;
    margin:0 auto;
}

div.text span.info {
    width: 250px;       
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;  
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-transition: all .5s; 
    transition: all .5s;
}
```

[See Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/anpsmn/vw87gj00/2/)